# Fedora liveUSB how to boot to ram?

Tags: fedora, live-usb

I use Linux Mint mostly as OS. I wanted to try to use Fedora more. I wanted to boot liveUSB to ram, familiar `toram` option to pass to the kernel (although it is not kernel parameter, it AFAIK is passed further down the line of boot sequence) had not worked. I've tried web search and to my surprise most relevant (IMO) result for booting to ram was this post w/out any answers: https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?324932-Fedora-33-boot-live-to-ram

> the option rd.live.ram doesn't seem to work any more. Any idea how to
> boot live image to ram?

Is it definite - no boot to ram support for recent versions? Any historic reasons why has it been dropped? It was of particular surprise to me as I've found about [swap to ram](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SwapOnZRAM) in Fedora, which I don't recall reading about for Linux Mint / Ubuntu.

Comment: AFAIK It worked with Fedora 33. Let me check.

Comment: @Artem, it indeed looks like working.

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded the XFCE spin for Fedora 35 ( Fedora-Xfce-Live-x86_64-35-1.2.iso ) and the option is there however it looks like there's a bug and using the option (`rd.live.ram=1`) leads to a dead system **under** VirtualBox:

[image: booting with rd.live.ram=1]

Maybe it only affects the XFCE spin. I've filed a bug report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2035641

Comment: I downloaded Cinnamon edition of 35 and just booted with just `rd.live.ram` (no `=1`) and removed USB and started FF, so seems working fine. Artem, I'm a novice to Fedora, I've used to rely on googling in case of issues with Ubuntu. How do you advice me to proceed with Fedora if I did not find the answer to the first question I got via web search (and I consider boot to ram rather common one)? I've read there is less info in it than on Ubuntu, still... Do you understand my concern?

Comment: I booted in legacy, now want to try UEFI.

Comment: Fedora has its forums and an IRC channel, and, yes, it has far few users thus finding answers sometimes is difficult.

Comment: UEFI works. Why have you used `rd.live.ram=1`? Taking this as an example, where is it documented?

Comment: /usr/share/doc/dracut/dracut.html : `The compressed SquashFS image can be copied during boot to RAM at /run/initramfs/squashed.img by using the rd.live.ram=1 option.` That's from Fedora 35, so the option is there.

Comment: It's weird the Cinnamon spin works for you with this option. It bails out with the same error for me.

Comment: I use `rd.live.ram` replacing `quiet` with it, do you too? I see `copying image to ram` on boot, it stops there for a minute

Comment: I removed `rhgb` and `quiet` and added the option.

Comment: I left rhgb I don't know what it means. New issue now - laptop do not wake after suspend not from opening lid, even power button does not work. I've read Fedora is rather stable, I want it run to days. That is after I saw you gave local link to docs, not web one. I like it btw if it is there.

Comment: RHGB = RedHat Graphical Boot, i.e. use fancy animations and don't show anything in console.

Comment: `rhgb` is not explained in `/usr/share/doc/dracut/dracut.html` btw, resume in not to ram works, gona try `rd.live.ram` again.

Comment: `rd.live.ram=1` also worked, maybe it is a hardware issue on your side.